# Varying Vertical Position of Sprite During Movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics, sprite

I have sprites in my iOS application that move across the screen horizontally, both left to right and right to left.  For most of these sprites, a straight line or a well-defined arc is acceptable.  I have some sprites, however, that I would like to have move a little more randomly, specifically varying the vertical position of the sprite as it moves.

In the following code, "y_variant_" is an ivar that specifies the degree of variance that I would like to apply.  It is a smaller value for natural objects like birds or man-made objects like paper airplanes, which should only move a small amount up and down as they fly, but a larger value for natural objects like insects and bees, which have much greater variance.

This is the code that I am currently using (the "update:" method for the sprite):

```
//  track/vary the object as it moves along its path...
- ( void ) update: ( ccTime ) delta

{

    //  ask director for the window size...
    CGSize const size = [ [ CCDirector sharedDirector ] winSize ];

    //  get the current position of the projectile...
    CGPoint const ptRaw = [ self position ];

    //  create a variant of the vertical position for "intelligent" items...
    CGPoint const pt = ( y_variant_
                       ? ccp( ptRaw.x
                            , ptRaw.y + y_variant_ * (float)( rand( ) % 25 ) * 0.02f - fmodf( ptRaw.x, y_variant_ )
                            )
                       : ptRaw
                       );
    [ self setPosition: pt ];
        :
        :
        :
        //  if we're supposed to stop the projectile on impact (a "brick wall", etc.)...
        if ( fStopProjectile == ObjectImpactActionStop )

            {

            //  object impact, if this is a "smart" projectile (i.e., something with a brain)...
            if ( y_variant_ )

                {

                //  move the projectile around the object...
                CCAction * const move = [ CCMoveTo actionWithDuration: 0.25f
                                                             position: ccpAdd( [ self position ]
                                                                             , ccp( - CS_IMAGE_OBJECT_W
                                                                                  , CS_IMAGE_OBJECT_H
                                                                                  )
                                                                             )
                                        ];

                [ self runAction: move ];

                }  // end "smart" projectile

            }  //  end projectile impact
        :
        :
        :
    return;

}  //  end update
```

You'll notice that there's logic involving collision with solid objects: if a solid obstruction (wall, building, etc.) is encountered, the object backs up and moves vertically to avoid the obstacle.

The problem that I'm running into is that the viewed motion is **very** erratic for the larger values of "y_variant_", and I would like it to appear smoother....

Even if you don't have a solution, any comments as to what can be improved or investigated would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

p.s.:  If you're feeling ambitious, one of the suggestions from a user was to have the bee *very* occasionally loop around backwards and then continue its path.  Once I've fixed the current "bouncing" problem, I'll incorporate that, so please keep that in mind....

Comment: Thanks to whoever corrected the tags for this question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple answer to your question. But if you're using Cocos2d, I would look into using actions instead of manually positioning the sprites. So to reiterate, I recommend you look into using actions. But here's a simple example that might help if you stick with manual positioning:

```
#define kAmountToMovePerFrameInY 10.0 / 60.0

@property float posYCurrentlyMovingTo;
@property SomeSpriteClass *theSpriteMoving;
@property float someXPosition;
@property float nextMoveAmount;


-(void)doStuffDuringUpdate
{


    if (_theSpriteMoving.position.y < labs(_posYCurrentlyMovingTo)) {
        //sprite is still moving to its position

        _theSpriteMoving.position = CGPointMake(_someXPosition, _theSpriteMoving.position.y + _nextMoveAmount);

    }else{
        float variationAmountInY = arc4random_uniform(200) - 100.0;
        _posYCurrentlyMovingTo = variationAmountInY;
        _nextMoveAmount = variationAmountInY * kAmountToMovePerFrameInY;


    }


}
```

Comment: I'm already using actions to move the sprite across the screen (CCMoveTo for straight lines and CBezierTo for arcs).  How can I modify that and still add the randomization based on the "y_variant_" value?

Comment: What I have above still works to randomize manually, but I'd be sticking with actions across the board and just randomizing the values for the given action, using multiple actions, etc.

Comment: So instead of varying a single CCMoveTo or CCBezierTo by hijacking the "update:" method, you'd recommend pre-programming multiple move actions and stringing them together?  I've tried that, but it brings up an issue when I tried implementing it:  the "live" projectiles (birds, bees, insects, etc.) alter their path when they encounter a solid object (walls, etc.), and that got rather difficult when the path was pre-defined....  That's why I'm trying to do it dynamically in the "update:" method.

Comment: Sounds like you've for it sorted out then, and the code above meets your needs for manually movement spaced out to prevent jarring visuals.